# prove or disprove: for every function $f : \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}, 0\leq f(n) \leq n,$ the graph of $f$ has an infinite set of collinear points

Tags: geometry, functions

> Let $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,\cdots\}$. Prove or disprove: for every function $f : \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}, 0\leq f(n) \leq n,$ the graph of $f$ has an infinite set of collinear points.

I think the claim is false and a counterexample is $f(x)=\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$. Clearly for all n in $\mathbb{N}$, $0\leq f(n)\leq \sqrt{n}\leq n$. Intuitively, one can't draw a line passing through infinitely many point of the function. I think it might be useful to use a proof by contradiction. Assume such a line $L$ does exist. Clearly $f(x)$ takes the same value for $x\in [k^2, (k+1)^2 - 1]$ for some nonnegative integer $k$. Let the equation of $L$ be $y=mx +b$. Then by assumption there are infinitely many points so that $\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor = mx + b$. Could one derive a contradiction by showing that $\dfrac{\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor - b}x = m$ has only finitely many solutions in positive integers, and if so, how?

Comment: Visually, the graph of $f$ stays within a half-parabola that opens around the positive $x$ axis. But any line (with non-zero slope) eventually gets outside of that parabola when $x$ gets big enough. I.e. you can prove your last statement by bringing $x$ over to the right hand side, and comparing the growth rates of $x^1$ and $x^{1/2}$ - you don't even have to restrict yourself to integers.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor-b}{x}=0$, so $m$ must be $0$. But then you are left with finding infinitely many $x$ such that $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor=b$, clearly impossible.

Comment: Another more intuitive counterexample in my opinion would be $f(n)=\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor$, i.e., $f(1)=0,f(2)=f(3)=1,f(4)=f(5)=f(6)=f(7)=2$ and so on.